# Ruby: Chrome browser is not launching

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, capybara, webdrivers-gem

Recently I have installed `gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'` and trying to launch a chrome browser. But it's not working.

**Code**:

```
@app = Driver.new(Capybara::Session.new(:selenium_chrome))
Webdrivers::Chromedriver.current_version
```

**Error log**:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/login_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require_relative '../pages/nav_bar.rb'

SyntaxError:
  /Users/madhan_kumaravel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.8/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chrome_finder.rb:83: syntax error, unexpected '.'
  ....VersionInfo.ProductVersion")&.strip
  ...                               ^
  /Users/madhan_kumaravel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.8/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chrome_finder.rb:87: syntax error, unexpected '.'
          System.call(location, '--product-version')&.strip
                                                      ^
  /Users/madhan_kumaravel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.8/gems/webdrivers-4.1.2/lib/webdrivers/chrome_finder.rb:91: syntax error, unexpected '.'
          System.call(location, '--version')&.strip
```

Comment: It seems the gem is using Ruby 2.3 syntax (`&.` - safe navigation operator) but you try to run it on 2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Marek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279683/marek-lipka) mentioned in the comments, the gem is using the [safe navigation operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator) which is only available in Ruby 2.3 and above. Either upgrade to Ruby 2.3 or downgrade webdrivers to 3.9.4, e.g. `gem 'webdrivers', '~> 4.0'`.

I looked through the [code for 3.9.4](https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers/tree/01cc57be24d61f87b74d43d169fba41f0174a40a) and they don't seem to use the safe navigation operator, so it's worth giving a shot.